# Wordpress: shortcode doesn't work when getting post content using function get_post_field()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I want to get the post content by id outside the loop, so i am using following code:

```
    echo get_post_field('post_content', $postid);
```

It works fine, however, if the post contains any shortcodes, the shortcodes don't work properly. It only echoes the shortcode as plain text.

Example: I'm using following code in editor to display image and caption text inder the image:

```
    [caption id="attachment_23" align="alignnone" width="300"]<img class="size-medium wp-image-23 " alt="" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Desert-300x225.jpg" width="300" height="225" /> this is caption[/caption]
```

But when i get this post content using function `get_post_field()`, Instead of displaying caption text, it displays:

```
    [caption id="attachment_23" align="alignnone" width="300"]this is caption[/caption]
```

Any solution?

N.B: I am using ajax to get the contents

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This will work:

```
echo do_shortcode(get_post_field('post_content', $postid));
```

**Edit**

If you want to forcefully output shortcode within Ajax, please see [running shortcode inside AJAX request](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/running-shortcode-inside-ajax-request?replies=9#post-5324569)

Comment: This works, but i am trying to get the content using ajax request. in that case it doesn't work :(

Comment: @user3396122 You can't output shortcode using ajax. Because when doing ajax request the `admin-ajax.php` doesn't know about `shortcodes.php` file. You don't have access to whole wp environment when request with ajax.

Comment: For future readers: If you want to forcefully output shortcode within Ajax, please [see](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/running-shortcode-inside-ajax-request?replies=9#post-5324569)

Answer (score 17):

You need to filter your content before displaying it, so try the following code:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $postid) );
```

---

**Update:**
You can't output shortcodes using ajax calls hooked into `wp_ajax`.
`WP Ajax` runs both public as well as closed calls via `admin.php`. This means that you don't have access to the whole wp environment, such as `do_shortcode()`, which is inside `/wp-includes/shortcodes.php`.

Comment: This works, but i am trying to get the content using ajax request. in that case it doesn't work :(

Comment: This work right be cause do_shortcode wrong converts new lines.